# how to pass textbox value from jsp to servlet without using name property of textbox

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to pass textbox value from jsp to servlet without using name property of textbox

In jsp page

```
input type="text"  id ="name"
```

In servlet

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

But can't access value

(Code formatting included)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to access the value of input is by using the `name` field.

```
<input type="text" id="idFirstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

To access the value of the above field you would write something like this in servlet.

```
request.getParameter("firstName");
```

But you can also access the value of the input by id using javascript and sending the value back to the servlet by setting the parameters in the request object.

```
document.getElementById("idFirstName").value;
```

Note: I would suggest you to access the value only using the `name` field.